# Js: turning file into module gives "[function] is declared but its value is never read" error

Tags: javascript

Hi sorry if this is a stupid question but I cant find the answer anywhere.

I have a js file in which I draw on canvases and I have just removed a function from it as I would like to use it in another js file I have. I have then imported the getPosition function into the drawBalls.js file as so:

```
import {getPosition} from "../Useful_Scripts/divPosition.js";
```

And that seems to work alright (as in it gives me no errors). However, right underneath that I have a function draw which starts off like this:

```
function draw(canvas){
  const maxRadius = 10;
  const minRadius = 5;
  etc;
```

Which is no longer works given the error ''draw' is declared but its value is never read.'. It does work though if I remove the import code and paste the getPosition function into drawBalls.js and remove type="module" from the script tag.

I have this in my html file where I try to draw on my canvas:

```
<script type="module" src="../Scripts/Project_1/drawBalls.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        draw(canvas1);
    });
</script>
```

Can someone please explain as to why it no longer works as soon as the file is turned into a module?

**Update**
I have changed my html file to

```
<script type="module" >
  import {draw} from "../Scripts/Project_1/drawBalls.js"
   window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    draw(canvas1);
  });
```

This works!

Comment: You include your `drawBalls.js` as a module, but you don't export the `draw` function from your module ...

Comment: @derpirscher — Just exporting it wouldn't do any good. Exports don't become globals.

Comment: @derpirscher I was just about to say the same thing.

Comment: @Quentin right. but there are different ways to resolve this situation (but OP provides too little details). One could be, just not including `drawballs.js` as a module. Another one would be using the module correctly ...

Comment: @derpirscher — Yes, but just exporting `draw` is neither of those things and, by itself, won't work.

Comment: @derpirscher As I understand I need to turn `drawBalls.js` into a module so that I am able to import the `getPosition` function. Is there then a way to avoid doing this or doing it differently? Also what other details could I provide?

Comment: "As I understand I need to turn drawBalls.js into a module so that I am able to import the getPosition function" — Yes. And you have. Now do one of the things I suggested in my answer to get it to work with your event listener.

Comment: @Quentin can you check the update that I wrote. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavinciCake – That is what I said to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scope of a module is *that module* and not the global scope.

The `draw` method only exists inside that module.

Either:

- Put the `addEventListener` code inside `drawBalls.js`
- `export` the `draw` function and then `import` it into your other script instead of loading `drawBall.js` with a `<script>` element.

You can also explicitly assign `draw` to be a property of `window`, but that is a dirty hack and I do not recommend it.

Comment: So by turning it into a module I have (in loose terms) made my draw function private?

Comment: Yes. Modules are designed to avoid polluting the global scope with local variables.

Answer (score -1):

> You include your drawBalls.js as a module, but you don't export the draw function from your module –
> derpirscher

You're using the script as a module. Pretend you're making an NPMjs package, and you build index.js. How would you require that module and use it?

Before requiring your package, in index.js you'll need to export it to import / include it.

It's very basic syntax with `module.exports`:

###### drawBalls.js

```js
module.exports = draw;
```

EDIT: The above code is for CommonJS modules. Use `export` instead (just like you would `import`):

```js
export draw;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? Im new to this and am having trouble following. I have tried to use what you wrote but I get an error saying that `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Comment: That is how you set up exports for CommonJS modules; browsers don't support that module format. Also, as I pointed out in a comment, exporting `draw` is not sufficient to make this work. It won't turn it into a global.

Comment: @Quentin I don't work that much on client-side modules, so I can't really make a great answer. I gave it a try though.